# Synchronizing header and headings font

Tags: fonts, sectioning, header-footer

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \section{First Section}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

How to make header font the same as headings font?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for

```
 \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\bfseries}
```

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \section{First Section}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]